# SSH Tunneling while connected to a VPN is blocked from work, but works when I'm on the home network

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, firewall

I would like to be able to `ssh tunnel` into a machine that is connected to a VPN at work.

**Setup**

- `Machine A` - Creates the `SSH tunnel` in Machine B
- `Machine B` - Connects to the work `VPN`

Situation

```
╒═════════╤══════════════╤═════════════════════╤══════════════╤═════════════════════╕
│         │ Work Network │ Work Network on VPN │ Home network │ Home network on VPN │
├─────────┼──────────────┼─────────────────────┼──────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ Can SSH │ Yes          │ No                  │ Yes          │ Yes                 │
╘═════════╧══════════════╧═════════════════════╧══════════════╧═════════════════════
```

As you can see. It is not the VPN that is blocking my being able to `ssh` into `Machine B` as I am able to connect to the VPN on the same machine at home. So it is the work network that is blocking this but **ONLY** when I am connected to the VPN.

I am changed the `ssh` port to `2222` and `17832` but this made little difference, once connected to the VPN the connect will time out.

I am confused, is it possible that at work they block `ssh tunneling` but only when somebody is connected to the `VPN`?

Comment: Thanks tim for the comment. What confuses me is that I am able to ssh tunnel on the work network when I am not on the VPN. Its only when I am at work AND on the VPN that I am unable to ssh tunnel. So they not blocking port 22.

Comment: Weird, I doubt they could block anything through the tunnel, routers can't see what's inside the encrypted packets. They only see a destination address with corresponding ports.

Comment: I have updated the question, I am not sure. But is that clearer what the problem is? Indeed, I am so very confused by this situation lol

Comment: It may well be way their ACLs are written and how traffic is filtered when it goes through the Worknetwork-VPN-Internet at a guess. You might not be able to see encrypted traffic, but smarter firewalls can guess whats inside a tunnel and filter appropriately.

Comment: Ye I see, so its totally possible to block traffic if it is encrypted. So no hope for me basically?

Comment: @JamieHutber did you ever find the cause and solution of your problem? I'm facing the same.

Comment: Please see updated answer)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly work only allowed SSH on a certain set of IPs within their network.

This is to say, basically I could only connect to SSH through a VPN when I wasn't connected directly to the corporate network.

**Solution:**

```
I bought a 3G Mobile Wifi network that cost £30 a month with 20gb of data. 
There is simply no other way round this.
```